# Geometric probability expressed as a geometric series

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, random-variables

Suppose that we want to show that $P(X \le n) = (1 - p)^{n}$

Where X is a geometric random variable with probability of success p.

$P(X > n)$ can be written as a geometric series as follows:

$\Sigma_{X = n+1}^{\infty}(1 - p)^{n -1} = (1 - p)^{n}$

But how do I proof this? What is a and r in this particular geometric series?

Comment: $\sum$ expression looks messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It helps to start from the right place.

When $X$ is geometric with success rate $p$, then $X=n$ is the event of $n-1$ failures *before* the first success, so:

$$\mathsf P(X=n) = (1-p)^{n-1}p$$

So:$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(X>n) &=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty \mathsf P(X=k)\\&=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty (1-p)^{k-1} p\\&= p(1-p)^{n}~\sum_{r=0}^\infty (1-p)^r\\&~~\vdots\end{align}$$